# Can we run the linux kernel on specific cores in a Multi-core CPU?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, multicore

I'm making a brainwave detection device. 
I'll be taking an Octa-Core ARM processor for the software processing.
For the management of CPU cores, can I code Linux Kernel to strictly run on a specific set of cores? Let's say core 1, 2, and 3. 
But it should not be too strict as I also need to spawn the device driver on a separate core (let's take core 4). 
So is it possible to do so?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by "Linux" running on a specific set of cores (are you talking about the kernel, or userspace?), or "spawning a device driver" on a particular core. Do you just want to set default processor affinity?

Comment: yes, it is possible! one of the possibility is to use the device tree where the hardware to be used is described

Comment: I mean, the Linux Kernel will be running on specific set of Cores.
The main device specific driver will be spawned on a separate core (other than kernel cores).
And the rest of the cores will be for the User Space.

Comment: There is a paper about this topic: https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2010/ols2010-pages-101-108.pdf . It does not contain much info about the actual work but more sense of possibility.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways of doing it is to use the device-tree. As you know the kernel knows nothing about hardware so, at boot time, it retrieves info from the device tree where the hardware is described.
[Here](https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage), you can find some basic information. However, in the device tree, there should be a section like this:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    compatible = "acme,coyotes-revenge";

    cpus {
        cpu@0 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9";
        };
        cpu@1 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9";
        };
    };
};
```

Try to describe your hardware to be used by adding/deleting the nodes in the device tree.

Comment: The driver can run on an independent core.
And is there a way to limit the Kernel to a specific set of Cores?

Comment: the same way, no? try to specify CPU 0 - 1 and 6 if you want to use just those 3 CPUs and say us if it works

Comment: Thank you. The above mentioned process is relevant for drivers.
But can the entire Linux kernel on the CPU set?
For example, CPU 0 - 2.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: ok, which platform are you using? give us more details: tools, frameworks, how you generate your devicetree blob ect..

Comment: Thank you for your participation sir.
The project itself is in planning phase and I'm conducting a feasibility test whether such can be done.
Using Ubuntu with the latest Linux kernel and a Octa-core ARM processor will be the first preference.
The signal processing tools will be MATLAB based.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking for.

**Leaving Cores Unused?**

Whilst you might be able to get Linux to boot using only a subset of the cores in a machine, there's no point doing so. It begs the question, what are the unused cores going to be doing? They're not going to be available to software (application or driver code) you are running on Linux, because the Linux you've booted isn't using them.

Bear in mind that a core is simply a CPU that happens to be in the same memory address space as other cores. It has to run something, and it's normal to have chunks of OS running on it. There has to be something running on the core managing it (scheduling what's running on it). You can't just dump an application thread on to a CPU without there being something to provide OS services to it.

**Core Affinity?**

If you're interested in taking control of core affinity, there's functions for controlling which of your threads are running on which cores. Though I caution against them - it's a ton of work to do for each CPU model you wish to support, and you'll really struggle to beat what the Linux kernel does anyway. I've tried, and made only a tiny improvement over what Linux accomplished automatically. It wasn't worth it.

**Real Time Scheduling?**

Are you really looking for some real time performance? The best you can do with Linux is something like the PREEMPT_RT patch set (becoming more mainstream I think).

With this version of Linux, device drivers become threads, and are therefore pre-emptable just like anything else. So if you give the application / driver thread a high real time priority, it will (nearly) always win the "what's going to be scheduled next" decision that the kernel is going to make. PREEMPT_RT will also solve priority inversion, so if your thread gets blocked by a lower priority thread contending for the same resource, the kernel will do its best to sort things out.

If PREEMPT_RT's latency is not low enough for you, Linux is the wrong choice. VxWorks springs to mind.

Comment: I admit the question is little confusing as I'd put more in a single question. Apologies.
The Kernel will be running on our own micro-controller.
The most important device drivers will be running on a dedicated set of cores. 
My question is,
Can we strictly separate the CPU cores for user and kernel Space?
There is going to be heavy parallel signal processing for interpreting the brain waves. 
So will it be feasible to divide the CPU cores?

Comment: @MiteshG, no you can't. The kernel scheduler will run on every core. The schedulers will schedule whatever is ready to run (application and device driver threads) on whatever core they think is best. You can toy with controlling core affinity for your application threads, but you will struggle to make decisions better than the kernel. The best you can do is to set your threads to be real time priority, and at a higher priority than driver threads, on a PREEMPT_RT kernel. If that's still not low enough latency, you're using the wrong OS.

Comment: So, basically whatever that has be done for process management, has to be done in the Scheduler. 
Sir, have you worked on memory management? I have some different strategies in mind for signal processing (Brain Waves).
And lastly sir, can we stay in touch? There are no contact details of yours on stack overflow.